# verify sketchy equation with conditional expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I saw this sketchy equation and wondered what is correct or wrong and which assumptions are needed for (1) and (2) (maybe it is due to unfamiliar/sloppy notation):

$$\mathbb{E}[A|B=b] \overset{(1)}{=} \int a P(a|B=b) = \int a P(B=b|a) P(a) \overset{(2)}{=} \mathbb{E}[a P(B=b|a)]$$

(1) I thought I would need the conditional density $f_A(\centerdot|B=b)$, but looks intuitively ok. What is required for this to hold (if in any case it holds)?

(2) I do not get this. I would expect Fubini, but..

---

Step-by-step filling in details:

$$\mathbb{E}[A|B=b] \overset{(1)}{=} \int_\Omega a P(A=a|B=b) \propto \int_\Omega a P(B=b|A=a) P(A=a) \overset{(2)}{=} \mathbb{E}[a P(B=b|A=a)]$$

- $A$ and $B$ are random variables
- I assume that the integral are proportional, since according to Bayes the divisor is missing.
- $a$ inside $P$ meant the event $A=a$
- I added $\Omega$ as sample space to the integral, then the Integral should be $dP$? I am not sure.. Maybe the integral is in the pushforward measure of $A$.

Comment: What is your source? // First problem: what is P(a|B=b)? I do not know what this notation refers to. After that point, things get even worse, but one could want to explain this first bit.

Comment: There is no text source. I assume $P(A=a|B=b)$ is what is meant, where $A$ and $B$ are random variables. Possibly it is more a problem of filling in the missing details..

Comment: If A is continuous (as the integral sign seems to suggest) then P(A=a|B=b)=0 for every a, which indicates the identity as you wrote it cannot be true. My experience is that these so-called notational details are the most effective obstacle to any understanding of what is going on. And I must admit I have some trouble reconciling "I saw this sketchy equation" and "There is no text source".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $A$ and $B$ have densities $f_A$ and $f_B$ respectively and that $A$ conditionally on $B$ and $B$ conditionally on $A$ have conditional densities $f_{A\mid B}(\ \mid\ )$ and $f_{B\mid A}(\ \mid\ )$ respectively. Then the joint density $f_{A,B}$ of $(A,B)$ exists and is such that, for almost every $(a,b)$,
$$
f_{A,B}(a,b)=f_{A\mid B}(a\mid b)f_B(b)=f_{B\mid A}(b\mid a)f_A(a).
$$
Thus, for every measurable function $u$,
$$
E[u(A)\mid B=b]=\int_\mathbb Ru(a)f_{A\mid B}(a\mid b)\mathrm da=f_B(b)^{-1}\int_\mathbb Ru(a)f_{B\mid A}(b\mid a)f_A(a)\mathrm da,
$$
where the first = sign is a definition and the second = sign follows from the identity above. Consequently, the "Step-by-step filling in details" suggested in the question is mostly correct, with three exceptions. First, the integrals are not on $\Omega$ but on the image set of $A$, which we assumed to be $\mathbb R$. Second, when the random variables $A$ and $B$ have densities, every $P(A=a|B=b)$, $P(B=b|A=a)$ and $P(A=a)$ is actually zero. Third, notations such as $E[aP(B=b|A=a)]$ cannot be recommended.

Comment: What if one random variable is discrete, e.g. $B$.Then $f_B \neq 0$ and the setting seems a bit different.

Comment: If $B$ is discrete, there is no density $f_B$. Densities are for absolutely continuous random variables only. You might want to learn to distinguish between (absolutely continuous random variables+densities) vs (discrete random variables+sum of weights).

Comment: I wonder: if $A:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and $B: \Omega \to \{b_1,...,b_m\}$ and we assume $f_A$ exists, how to formally continue from there? So there is no $f_B$ but what about $f_{A,B}$ and the conditional densities and when do they exist? How would they look like? How does the integral equality look like then?